# VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences putting spectograms inside a np array

Tags: python, numpy, librosa

```
for g in genres:
    genre_path = os.path.join(data_path, g)
    for filename in os.listdir(genre_path):
        song_path = os.path.join(genre_path, filename)
        print(f"{song_path}")
        y.append(g)
        X_song, sr = librosa.load(song_path)
        spectrogram = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=X_song, sr=sr, n_fft=2048, hop_length=512)
        db_spectrogram = librosa.power_to_db(spectrogram, ref=np.max)
        X.append(db_spectrogram)
```

I have this code that loops through a Training folder then a subfolders called genre path that contains guitar chords such as Am Bm and then performs a spectrogram on them. I then pass X into a np array to feed it into the neural network but get the error
VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays
**X = np.array(X)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (128,98) into shape (128,)**

This is the code after the for loop that is causing the error

```
X = np.array(X)
y = np.array(y)

le = LabelEncoder()
y_encoded = le.fit_transform(y)
y_one_hot = np_utils.to_categorical(y_encoded)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y_one_hot, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
model = Sequential()
```

Comment: I expect you'll need to make all your spectrograms the same shape. If the audio is all at the same sample rate then they should all be the same size in one dimension at least (if they're at different sample rates it'll be trickier to do). You'll then have to find the one with the largest time dimension and zero pad all the smaller ones to be the same size.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try padding all the spectrogram arrays with zeros to make them the same size before converting to a NumPy array. One way to do this (assuming all the sample rate and therefore the number of mel-spaced frequency bins is the same for each song) is as follows (where I've assumed `X` is your list if spectrograms):

```py
# go through X and get the maximum number of time bins over all spectrograms
maxt = max([x.shape[-1] for x in X])

# create numpy array with zeros padded data to the time axis
X = np.array(
    [
        np.pad(x, ((0, 0), (0, maxt - x.shape[-1])), constant_values=0)
        for x in X
    ]
)
```